# Update input name with iteration and update form on remove

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I a need to create an HTML form where a user can add a new row and then remove one if necessary.

I have this partially working; I can add to the table, and remove to the table. However, for particular reasons I need each row in the table to have the same iteration number e.g. [0], [1] for the next row and so on.

I have tried different methods on getting this to work but my knowledge of jquery is amateur at best! I have scoured the internet and there is nothing I can find that solves my issue precisely or coherently.

```
  <table id="options-table">                    
    <tr>
      <td width="10">ID</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>From</td>
      <td>Cost</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input  name="number" type="text" value="0" /></td>
      <td><input class="one" name="name[" type="text" /></td>
      <td><input class="two" name="from[" type="text" /></td>
      <td><input class="three" name="cost[" type="text" /></td>                        
      <td><input type="button" class='del' value='Delete' /></td>
    </tr>                  
    <tr>
      <td><input name="number" type="text" value="1"  /></td>
      <td><input class="one" name="name[" type="text"  /></td>
      <td><input class="two" name="from[" type="text" /></td>
      <td><input class="three" name="cost[" type="text"  /></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add More" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

$('table').on('click', '.add', function(){
  $(this).val('Delete');
  $(this).attr('class','del');
  var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input name='number' type='text' /></td> <td><input class='one' name='name[' type='text' /></td> <td><input class='two' name='from[' type='text' /></td><td><input class='three' name='cost[' type='text' /> </td><td><input type='button' class='add' value='Add More' /></td></tr>";
  $("tr:last").after(appendTxt);    
    $("input[name='number']").each(function(ind) {
        $(this).val(ind + 1);
      });



$("input.one").each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') +i + ']');

});
```

The issue I am facing is that on the removal of a row, I am getting the addition of the number again, with a new ]

It should be Row 1: name[0], from[0], cost[0] and so on.

Anyone that can point me more precisely at what I should be looking at? cheers

Comment: A simplistic approach would be to rename the fields when ever you remove one, to force the numbers to be contiguous.  Then when you add a row the next number is simply the number of existing rows.

Comment: An alternative is to *hide* the rows that are "deleted" (with a hidden input set to indicate virtual deletion) then adding new rows becomes trivial as you don't need to do any renaming/renumbering and the POST keeps the numbers contiguous (is this for ASP.Net MVC?)

Comment: Both work, thanks for the ideas! Exploring the virtual deletion idea @freedomn-m - and spot on with the guesswork.

Comment: Related: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/